# NuGet doesn't show packages to install

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I don't know how to fix it.Does any body know what to do? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: try restarting your VS

Comment: See if you can ping the nuget server, it may be down/inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

If no Windows HTTP proxy is specified, NuGet uses (if present) the HTTP Proxy specified in the environment variable http_proxy.
This can be solved my removing `http_proxy`

Open `System Properties` > `Advanced` > `Environment Variables`. Find the `http_proxy` variable (in `System variables`), select and delete it.